# How can I write an Exif header without recompressing the JPEG, in .NET?

Tags: .net, image, exif

I have a [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) image that I want to set an [Exif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) header to (particularly, Author).

In .NET, I can do this relatively easy using GetPropertyItem and SetPropertyItem, but in order for that change to be persisted to the actual .JPG file, I need to *Save* it, which basically recompresses the image.

Is there any way to do this without recompressing?

Comment: Closing as exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038206/net-c-library-for-lossless-exif-rewriting

Comment: That has no valid answers whatsoever...

Answer (score 1):

I believe [exiv2net](http://code.google.com/p/exiv2net/) library (a .NET wrapper on top of exiv2) may be what you're looking for.