# How to remove EXIF data without recompressing the JPEG?

Tags: unix, imagemagick, jpeg, exif

I want to remove the EXIF information (including thumbnail, metadata, camera info... everything!) from JPEG files, but I don't want to recompress it, as recompressing the JPEG will degrade the quality, as well as usually increasing the file size.

I'm looking for a Unix/Linux solution, even better if using the command-line. If possible, using ImageMagick (convert tool). If that's not possible, a small Python, Perl, PHP (or other common language on Linux) script would be ok.

There is a similar question, but [related to .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813676/how-can-i-write-an-exif-header-without-recompressing-the-jpeg-in-net).

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/260810/how-can-i-read-and-remove-meta-exif-data-from-my-photos-using-the-command-line

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove *all* EXIF information? The EXIF Orientation information is crucial for displaying the image rotated the right way. If you remove it, you may find that the images are displayed 90 degrees rotated from what you expect. Also, colour profiles are stored in EXIF metadata, which affects how the colours of the image are displayed.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

exiftool does the job for me, it's written in perl so should work for you on any o/s

https://exiftool.org/

usage :

```
exiftool -all= image.jpg
```

UPDATED - as PeterCo explains below this will remove ALL of the tags. if you just want to remove the EXIF tags then you should use

```
exiftool -EXIF= image.jpg
```

Comment: Some other interesting options: "-o outfile.jpg" or "-out outfile.jpg", "-overwrite_original" or "-overwrite_original_in_place", "-P" or "-preserve", "-r" or "-recurse"

Comment: I just came across this thread looking for the same thing.  I just thought I'd add a comment here for Ubuntu users: The script is available in the Ubuntu repos as libimage-exiftool-perl:

`sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl`

Comment: Just like Denilson Sá mentioned, there are other interesting opitons. My favorite, to know at least how the meta data look like (before and/or after using the command given by oedo): `exiftool image.jpg`

Comment: Or with homebrew `brew install exiftool`

Comment: If you **really** trust the program add `-overwrite_original` switch and the program will not create the backup files.

Comment: Seems like all links on the linked site are dead now (HTTP 404).

Comment: The accepted usage with the option -all= removes ALL tags from your image.jpg! The correct answer would be `exiftool -EXIF= image.jpg`

Comment: @PeterCo Technically Exif data can be embedded inside XMP (and GIF images only support XMP). If you're stripping Exif there's a good chance you also want to strip XMP and IPTC, although probably not ICC profiles (which is what would happen when stripping "all").

Comment: @PeterCo And even then I don't want to strip all EXIF tags.. just the thumbnail!  For me at least, that's `exiftool -thumbnailimage= FILE`

Comment: Note that `exiftool -all= file.jpg` will remove even the "orientation" metadata, which will make some photos appear to be rotated the wrong way.

Answer (score 107):

With imagemagick:

```
convert <input file> -strip <output file>
```

Comment: Sorry, but -strip does not work as expected, since ImageMagick still recompress the JPEG file.

Comment: Note, by the way, that "-strip" might be useful if someone is doing other transformations with the file. Also note that "-thumbnail 123x456" is ALMOST equivalent to "-strip -resize 123x456".

Comment: +1 because this was miles easier than downloading a new tool.

Comment: Note `-strip` removes color profiles. For anyone trying to strip EXIF data without losing profile information, see my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17516878/1854499

Comment: OP should update this answer, since it's twice wrong.

Comment: When trying to use ImageMagick to strip exif data, I noticed that I ended up with a larger file than what I started with. This leads me to believe that Imagemagick is encoding the data you want stripped away, and is storing it somewhere else in the file. Call me old fashioned, but when I remove something from a file, I want a file size the be smaller if not the same size. Any other results suggest data mining.

Comment: Also note that `-strip` works not only with `convert`, but with a lot of other IM commands as well (i.e. I used `mogrify`)

Answer (score 52):

ImageMagick has the [-strip](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip) parameter, but it recompresses the image before saving. Thus, this parameter is useless for my need.

[This topic from ImageMagick forum](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10895) explains that there is no support for JPEG lossless operations in ImageMagick (whenever this changes, please post a comment with a link!), and suggests using [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) (from libjpeg):

```
jpegtran -copy none -progressive image.jpg > newimage.jpg
jpegtran -copy none -progressive -outfile newimage.jpg image.jpg
```

(If you are unsure about me answering my own question, read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/moving-a-personal-technical-blog-to-stackoverflow-serverfault/2729#2729) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not))

Comment: Tried the jpegtran method but  in most cases it increase the filesize instead of decreasing it. In most cases you want to do this to decrease the filesize.

Comment: When trying to use ImageMagick to strip exif data, I noticed that I ended up with a larger file than what I started with. This leads me to believe that Imagemagick is encoding the data you want stripped away, and is storing it somewhere else in the file. Call me old fashioned, but when I remove something from a file, I want a file size the be smaller if not the same size. Any other results suggest data mining.

Comment: A minor point: for me, none of the 2 commands listed worked, instead the following works:

`jpegtran -copy none image.jpg newimage.jpg`

Comment: @Codebeat You need to add param `-progressive` This will reduce size.

Comment: Note that `jpegtran -copy none file.jpg` will remove the "orientation" metadata, which will make some photos appear to be rotated the wrong way.

Answer (score 42):

You might also want to look into [Exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org/) -- it's really fast (C++ *and* no recompression), it's command line, and it also provides a library for EXIF manipulation you can link against. I don't know how many Linux distros make it available, but in CentOS it's currently available in the base repo.

Usage:

```
exiv2 rm image.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is the first one that does the job very well without quality loss and blazing fast! Yo deserve a +100! But to remove ALL type of headers I have to specify the -da option otherwise it will not remove adobe photoshop/creator info from jpg's. I'm on Windows anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to confirm that exiv2 would show GPS location info so that I could see that it was gone after. The default option for print is "summary" which excludes GPS info. To see all info you have to use:
exiv2 -pa pr image.jpg

Comment: Please note that this tool destroyed quality of some of my JPEGs, luckily I had a backup

Comment: @SteelBrain, that's really strange – can you share one of the JPEG images affected by this?

Comment: This is the safest solution

Comment: Easiest solution for batches and comes built into my linux distro, so no need to trust a third party for something like exiftool.

Comment: Note that `exiv2 rm image.jpg` will remove the "orientation" metadata, which will make some photos appear to be rotated the wrong way.

Answer (score 24):

I'd propose `jhead`:

```
man jhead
jhead -purejpg image.jpg
```

Only 123Kb on debian/ubuntu, it's fast, and it only touches EXIF keeping the image itself intact. Note that you need to create a copy if you want to preserve the original file with EXIF in it.

Answer (score 3):

I recently undertook this project in C.  The code below does the following:

1) Gets the current orientation of the image.

2) Removes all data contained in `APP1` (Exif data) and `APP2` (Flashpix data) by blanking.

3) Recreates the `APP1` orientation marker and sets it to the original value.

4) Finds the first `EOI` marker (End of Image) and truncates the file if nessasary.

Some things to note first are:

1) This program is used for my Nikon camera.  Nikon's JPEG format adds somthing to the very end of each file it creates.  They encode this data on to the end of the image file by creating a second `EOI` marker.  Normally image programs read up to the first `EOI` marker found.  Nikon has information after this which my program truncates.

2) Because this is for Nikon format, it assumes `big endian` byte order.  If your image file uses `little endian`, some adjustments need to be made.

3) When trying to use `ImageMagick` to strip exif data, I noticed that I ended up with a larger file than what I started with.  This leads me to believe that `Imagemagick` is encoding the data you want stripped away, and is storing it somewhere else in the file.  Call me old fashioned, but when I remove something from a file, I want a file size the be smaller if not the same size.  Any other results suggest data mining.

And here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

// Declare constants.
#define COMMAND_SIZE     500
#define RETURN_SUCCESS     1
#define RETURN_FAILURE     0
#define WORD_SIZE         15

int check_file_jpg (void);
int check_file_path (char *file);
int get_marker (void);
char * ltoa (long num);
void process_image (char *file);

// Declare global variables.
FILE *fp;
int orientation;
char *program_name;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
// Set program name for error reporting.
    program_name = basename(argv[0]);

// Check for at least one argument.
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s IMAGE_FILE...\n", program_name);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

// Process all arguments.
    for(int x = 1; x < argc; x++)
        process_image(argv[x]);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void process_image (char *file)
{
    char command[COMMAND_SIZE + 1];

// Check that file exists.
    if(check_file_path(file) == RETURN_FAILURE)
        return;

// Check that file is an actual JPEG file.
    if(check_file_jpg() == RETURN_FAILURE)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return;
    }

// Jump to orientation marker and store value.
    fseek(fp, 55, SEEK_SET);
    orientation = fgetc(fp);

// Recreate the APP1 marker with just the orientation tag listed.
    fseek(fp, 21, SEEK_SET);
    fputc(1, fp);

    fputc(1, fp);
    fputc(18, fp);
    fputc(0, fp);
    fputc(3, fp);
    fputc(0, fp);
    fputc(0, fp);
    fputc(0, fp);
    fputc(1, fp);
    fputc(0, fp);
    fputc(orientation, fp);

// Blank the rest of the APP1 marker with '\0'.
    for(int x = 0; x < 65506; x++)
        fputc(0, fp);

// Blank the second APP1 marker with '\0'.
    fseek(fp, 4, SEEK_CUR);

    for(int x = 0; x < 2044; x++)
        fputc(0, fp);

// Blank the APP2 marker with '\0'.
    fseek(fp, 4, SEEK_CUR);

    for(int x = 0; x < 4092; x++)
        fputc(0, fp);

// Jump the the SOS marker.
    fseek(fp, 72255, SEEK_SET);

    while(1)
    {
// Truncate the file once the first EOI marker is found.
        if(fgetc(fp) == 255 && fgetc(fp) == 217)
        {
            strcpy(command, "truncate -s ");
            strcat(command, ltoa(ftell(fp)));
            strcat(command, " ");
            strcat(command, file);
            fclose(fp);
            system(command);
            break;
        }
    }
}

int get_marker (void)
{
    int c;

// Check to make sure marker starts with 0xFF.
    if((c = fgetc(fp)) != 0xFF)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: get_marker: invalid marker start (should be FF, is %2X)\n", program_name, c);
        return(RETURN_FAILURE);
    }

// Return the next character.
    return(fgetc(fp));
}

int check_file_jpg (void)
{
// Check if marker is 0xD8.
    if(get_marker() != 0xD8)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: check_file_jpg: not a valid jpeg image\n", program_name);
        return(RETURN_FAILURE);
    }

    return(RETURN_SUCCESS);
}

int check_file_path (char *file)
{
// Open file.
    if((fp = fopen(file, "rb+")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: check_file_path: fopen failed (%s) (%s)\n", program_name, strerror(errno), file);
        return(RETURN_FAILURE);
    }

    return(RETURN_SUCCESS);
}

char * ltoa (long num)
{
// Declare variables.
        int ret;
        int x = 1;
        int y = 0;
        static char temp[WORD_SIZE + 1];
        static char word[WORD_SIZE + 1];

// Stop buffer overflow.
        temp[0] = '\0';

// Keep processing until value is zero.
        while(num > 0)
        {
                ret = num % 10;
                temp[x++] = 48 + ret;
                num /= 10;
        }

// Reverse the word.
        while(y < x)
        {
                word[y] = temp[x - y - 1];
                y++;
        }

        return word;
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

We used this to remove latitude data from TIFF file:

`exiv2 mo -M"del Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude" IMG.TIF`
where you can use `exiv2 -pa IMG.TIF` to list all metadata.

Comment: OP asked for removing _everything_ from a JPEG, not for removing just GPSLatitude from a tiff file. Thus, this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for convenience:** If you are on Windows, you can apply a REG file to the registry, to install an entry in the context menu, so you can easily remove metadata by right-clicking the file and selecting the command.

For example (remember to edit the paths to point to where the executables are installed on your computer):

---

For JPEG,JPG,JPE,JFIF files: command "**Remove metadata**"
(using [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), preserves original file as backup)
`exiftool -all= image.jpg`

JPG-RemoveExif.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell\RemoveMetadata]
@="Remove metadata"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell\RemoveMetadata\command]
@="\"C:\\Path to\\exiftool.exe\" -all= \"%1\""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\jpegfile\shell\RemoveMetadata]
"Icon"="C:\\Path to\\exiftool.exe,0"
```

---

For PNG files: command "**Convert to minified PNG**"
(using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#strip), changes data overwriting original file)
`convert -background none -strip -set filename:n "%t" image.png "%[filename:n].png"`

PNG-Minify.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\pngfile\shell\ConvertToMinifiedPNG]
@="Convert to minified PNG"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\pngfile\shell\ConvertToMinifiedPNG\command]
@="\"C:\\Path to\\convert.exe\" -background none -strip -set filename:n \"%%t\" \"%1\" \"%%[filename:n].png\""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\pngfile\shell\ConvertToMinifiedPNG]
"Icon"="C:\\Path to\\convert.exe,0"
```

---

Related: [convert PNGs to ICO in context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823738/9638388).

Comment: OP explicitly asked for a UNIX/Linux solution thus this is pretty much irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Even though the question has unix tag, this is still SO, not Unix SE or Ask Ubuntu. I can think of a lot of times where I found an answer (that wasn't totally specific to the question) that helped me in someone else's question. We don't give answers solely for the benefit of the ones asking, you know... IMHO There's no need to be so strict with the rules; the question already has great answers at the top.

Comment: This is not how SO works. This is a Q&A site where answers should actually answer the question. And not a web-forum where it's common to post random apropos comments in any thread. For your use case, on SO, a better way is to post a new question regarding windows registry specifics, possibly directly together with your answer. Then you can add a comment for reference to a related question.

Answer (score 0):

For lossless EXIF strip you can use [libexif](https://libexif.github.io/), which is [available with cygwin](https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/exif/). Remove both EXIF and thumbnail to anonymize an image:

```
$ exif --remove --tag=0 --remove-thumbnail exif.jpg -o anonymized.jpg
```

Drag-n-drop `.bat` file for use with cygwin:

```
@ECHO OFF
exif --remove --tag=0 --remove-thumbnail %~1
```

Comment: This didn't remove the GPS location data when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use jpegoptim you can use it to remove the exif, too.

```
jpegoptim -s *
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it modifies the image (and there doesn't seem to be a `copy` option, and using the `-n` switch to not optimize the image also doesn't strip the EXIF data).