# Converting GIF's, PNG's and JPG's to .ICO files using Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, favicon

From: JPG, To: ICO;

```
/usr/bin/convert -resize x16 -gravity center -crop 16x16+0+0 input.jpg \
-transparent white -colors 256 output/favicon.ico
```

This is the output for the command line.

From: GIF's, PNG To: ICO;

```
/usr/bin/convert -resize x16 -gravity center -crop 16x16+0+0 input.png \
-flatten -colors 256 output/favicon.ico
```

I am having issues with transparency. I can't seem to get the right code for it, i have tried -channel alpha -negate, etc

This creates an image and when i apply to the site, it works with Firefox but none of the other browsers. IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari all hate it for some reason, it is a simple favicon.ico file. My conclusion is it must be my command somewhere is breaking. Please help?

Comment: Can you show a sample ICO file please?

Comment: This command, which is "like yours" seemed to work fine here: $ convert -resize 1
28x128 images/note.png -transparent white -colors 256 favicon.ico

Comment: I think I'm missing some bits: `convert convert: No encode delegate for this image format (favicon.ico) [No such file or directory].` Apparently Debian Jessie lacks `ICO` support in ImageMagick.  This worked for me: `icotool -c -o favicon.ico FILENAME`.  See http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/how-to-convert-a-png-to-ico-file-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 56):

To convert PNG to ICO, setting the sizes you want, and preserving transparency:
(works for ImageMagick 7.0 or newer)

```
convert -background transparent "favicon.png" -define icon:auto-resize=16,24,32,48,64,72,96,128,256 "favicon.ico"
```

In this example, the ico file will have 9 entries: 16x16 px, 24x24 px, etc (assuming it is square)

---

**Hint:**
If you are on Windows 7, you can save the code below to a REG file and apply it to the registry. This will create an entry in the context menu of PNG files called "Convert to ICO". When you right-click *file.png* and select this command, *file.png.ico* will be generated in the same folder.

InstallConvertToIcoCtxMenu.reg
(remember to replace the ImageMagick path with the path where it is installed on your computer)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Created with Default Programs Editor
; http://defaultprogramseditor.com/

; Edit Verb
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\pngfile\shell\ConvertToICO]
@="Convert to ICO"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\pngfile\shell\ConvertToICO\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick\\7.0.3-Q16\\convert.exe\" -background transparent \"%1\" -define icon:auto-resize=16,24,32,48,64,72,96,128,256 \"%1.ico\""
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\pngfile\shell\ConvertToICO]
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick\\7.0.3-Q16\\convert.exe,0"
```

[image: An entry is added to context menu]

Answer (score 46):

Add this option to `convert`:

```
-background transparent
```

However, keep in mind that your original image must actually have an alpha channel.  PNGs may have an alpha channel, JPEGs do not.

Answer (score 7):

One solution to the ICO problem would be not using it:

```
<link rel=icon href=/favicon.png>
```

Works in all browsers, and you get to use saner file format with better compression.

Comment: IE11+ supports this. But SVG support ([mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=366324)) would be even better.