# Recipe for creating Windows ICO files with ImageMagick?

Tags: icons, imagemagick

I would like to create `.ico` icon for my Windows application dynamically (from the SVG file) by using ImageMagick. How do I do that?

Microsoft [lists various color depth and size requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997636.aspx#winxpicons_step5) for the icon. ImageMagick has the [`-depth`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth) and [`-colors`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colors) options, but I'm not sure how to use them correctly in this case.

Additionaly, it looks like [Vista+ supports 256x256 hi-res icon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485.aspx) embedded into the very same `.ico` which can (should? must?) be a compressed PNG. How do I "join" the Windows XP icons and this new Vista icon into a single `.ico` file?

Comment: In case you're wondering, this is the *application* icon (the one sticked on the .exe itself).

Comment: ImageMagick [doesn't support 256x256 icons](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1577) and will break those files

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74392449/8583692

Answer (score 36, accepted):

ImageMagick has a recipe for this in their documentation, see [FavIcon Web Page Link Thumbnail](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#favicon)

Essentially you run the following:

```
convert image.png  -bordercolor white -border 0 \
          \( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 \) \
          \( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 \) \
          \( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 \) \
          \( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 \) \
          -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 favicon.ico
```

You can modify this to include larger resolutions as necessary and to change things like border, transparency settings etc.

Comment: In fact you should be able to omit `-bordercolor white -border 0` if you use `-alpha remove` instead of `-alpha off`.

Comment: Except the author wants to do this with an SVG. As pointed out in my answer using this command on an SVG will totally destroy the quality of the resulting icon as imagemagick only resizes the SVG after rasterizing.

Comment: @MalcolmMacLeod Yes you are quite right, converting direct from SVG using this method gives awful results

Comment: to convert from SVG I wonder if you can "convert to a large image" first (like png), or possibly use the density and resize oversampling trick: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13585

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't seem like ImageMagick alone can do this as it does not handle SVG resizing in a sane way (but instead resizes the SVG only after rasterizing which produces a horrid result)

By using inkscape to do the conversion it appears to be possible though, e.g. The following one liner should give you a usable icon with all icon sizes:

```
mkdir temp; declare -a res=(16 24 32 48 64 128 256); for f in *.svg; do for r in "${res[@]}"; do inkscape -z -e temp/${f}${r}.png -w $r -h $r $f; done; resm=( "${res[@]/#/temp/$f}" ); resm=( "${resm[@]/%/.png}" ); convert "${resm[@]}" ${f%%.*}.ico; done; rm -rf temp;
```

The above will not however give you 8 and 4 bit icons within the file (I think these are only needed for older windows versions that are no longer supported)
It should be possible with a bit more work to have it do these if you need them.

Comment: Can this work with 512 px resolution? I've seen elsewhere that ImageMagick doesn't allow for 512 ico sizes. I'm making icons that are going to go on a large 4k screen so I think it's smart to have a 512 resolution just in case.

Comment: @DavidA.French As far as I know yes (several of the modified answers based on mine above also contain a 512px ico); However its probably best to just give it a try and see?

Comment: It appears the mac solution relies on tiff2ico and the windows one while setting a 512 size does not actual produce a 512 icon. Anyway thanks for the help!

Comment: @DavidA.French [ImageMagick doesn't even work with 256x256 icon files](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1577). I tried and a lot of output files are broken

Comment: ImageMagick can be used instead of inkscape, however you need to use it in a specific way to get the same quality as with inkscape (details are in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423711/recipe-for-creating-windows-ico-files-with-imagemagick/69487280#69487280)). @phuclv, ImageMagick indeed has issue with 256x256 icons, but there is a workaround for that. Please look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423711/recipe-for-creating-windows-ico-files-with-imagemagick/69487280#69487280) for more details

Comment: @PolarBear Interesting thanks, not sure if this worked back when I wrote my answer or not, I don't recall anymore. My recollection is that any kind of SVG downsize imagemagick was creating a large raster image and then downscaling that but perhaps I miss some details.

If it works as you describe now then it s a better solution as it avoids needing an extra program to do the job.

Comment: @DavidA.French .ico files support only 256 px icons MAX. Only 1 byte is allocated for the image size in ICONDIRENTRY structure of the .ico file!

Answer (score 10):

```
magick convert in.jpg -define icon:auto-resize=16,48,256 -compress zip out.ico
```

http://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#define

Comment: I would add the 32 and 64 to the size list as well - then I think this is perfect for all Windows OS:s

Comment: I didn't notice any difference with or without '-compress zip', though

Comment: “convert.im6: width or height exceeds limit” — fixed by first resizing the input image to be 256 × 256 pixels. But the transparent parts in the original pngs turned white.

Answer (score 9):

I cleaned up Malcolm's solution, fixed a bug, and also made the script output tiffs so you can run tiff2icns in osx.

```bash
#! /bin/bash
# converts the passed-in svgs to tiff and ico

if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 svg1 [svg2 [...]]"
    exit 0
fi

temp=$(mktemp -d)
declare -a res=(16 24 32 48 64 128 256 512)
for f in $*; do
    mkdir -p $temp/$(dirname $f)
    for r in "${res[@]}"; do
        inkscape -z -e $temp/${f}${r}.png -w $r -h $r $f
    done
    resm=( "${res[@]/#/$temp/$f}" )
    resm=( "${resm[@]/%/.png}" )
    for filetype in ico tiff; do
        convert "${resm[@]}" ${f%%.*}.$filetype
    done
done
rm -rf $temp
```

Answer (score 7):

I have been struggling with the same problem. I have an SVG with the image of my icon and I need to create an `icon.ico` file from it. Let me describe the solutions I found:

### Step 1: Determine what resolutions to include inside the `icon.ico` file.

There are no clear guidelines about that. Even Microsoft ships its software with inconsistent icon resolutions. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236115/which-icon-sizes-should-my-windows-applications-icon-include) about that.
Therefore, I think the best we can do about it is to use [IconsExtract from Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html). With such tool, you can check the resolutions included in icons of popular modern Windows programs.

### Step 2: Create .png files for every resolution you want to include inside your `icon.ico` file.

Many answers suggest to use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/), but you can do everything with [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) in the following way (just in case, I checked that the resulted images are the same as if you used inkscape):

```
magick.exe convert -size 16x16 -background transparent -depth 8 MyIconImage.svg 16.png
...
magick.exe convert -size 256x256 -background transparent -depth 8 MyIconImage.svg 256.png
```

However, if you still want to use Inkscape, here's the command:

```
inkscape.exe MyIconImage.svg -w 16 -h 16 -o 16.png
```

Some answers also suggest using ImageMagick's `icon:auto-resize` command line argument to avoid creating separate PNG files for every resolution. I don't recommend using it because to get the best quality it is better to avoid resizing as it is less accurate than rendering SVG file into each resolution separately.

### Step 3: Assemble your icon.ico file.

```
magick.exe convert 16.png 20.png 24.png 32.png 40.png 48.png 64.png 256.png -compress jpeg icon.ico
```

`-compress jpeg` is used as a workaround for a specific [issue in ImageMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1577), as described in the following [comment](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/1577#issuecomment-839915074).
You can see details about created `icon.ico` file using the following command:

```
magick.exe identify icon.ico
```

### Powershell script "CreateIcoFromSvg.ps1"

Let me provide a powershell script which automates above-mentioned steps:

```
# You can download ImageMagick from: https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php
$imageMagick = "$PSScriptRoot/ImageMagick-7.1.0-portable-Q16-x64/magick.exe"

$svgIcon = "MySvgIcon.svg"
$iconResolutions = 16,20,24,32,40,48,64,256

# Create 16.png, ..., 256.png image files
$pngImages = @()
Foreach($r in $iconResolutions) {
    & $imageMagick convert -size "${r}x${r}" -background transparent -depth 8 $svgIcon "${r}.png"
    $pngImages += "${r}.png"
}

# Combine all PNG image files into an icon.ico file
& $imageMagick convert $pngImages -compress jpeg "icon.ico"

# Remove PNG files
Foreach($image in $pngImages) {
    Remove-Item $image
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to also include the PS script. The only thing missing is that there is no antialiasing and the sizing is, therefore, too rough.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the standard recipe from the [FAQ](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#favicon), modified to have all the resolutions mentioned in the [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511280.aspx#size) (except those under "Additional sizes...") (the other answer didn't have all resolutions desired)

```
 convert input.png -bordercolor white -border 0 ( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 ) ( -clone 0 -resize 24x24 ) ( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 ) ( -clone 0 -resize 40x40 ) ( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 ) ( -clone 0 -resize 64x64 ) ( -clone 0 -resize 256x256 ) -delete 0 -alpha off -colors 256 output.ico
```

Answer (score 4):

### Update in 2022

I recently realized that using by using `convert` you actually can't solve this task because `convert` turns all the input images into `bmp`s and change the color depth of the images.

I have thus updated my script to use `icotool` (`sudo apt install icoutils`):

```
#!/bin/bash

for size in 16 24 32 48 64 96 128 256; do
    inkscape --export-filename $size.png -w $size -h $size logo.svg >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
done

for size in 16 24 32 48; do

  convert -colors 256 +dither $size.png png8:$size-8.png
  convert -colors 16  +dither $size-8.png $size-4.png

done

convert 16.png 24.png 32.png 48.png 16-8.png 24-8.png 32-8.png 48-8.png 16-4.png 24-4.png 32-4.png 48-4.png 64.png 96.png 128.png 256.png logo.ico

icotool -c -o logo.ico 16.png 24.png 32.png 48.png 16-8.png 24-8.png 32-8.png 48-8.png 16-4.png 24-4.png 32-4.png 48-4.png 64.png 96.png -r 128.png -r 256.png

rm 16.png 24.png 32.png 48.png 16-8.png 24-8.png 32-8.png 48-8.png 16-4.png 24-4.png 32-4.png 48-4.png 64.png 96.png 128.png 256.png
```

### Original Answer

Building on all previous answers and correcting the following mistakes:

- Don't use `-color=256`, as you need 32-bit color versions for all sizes with modern Windows versions (Vista+)
- Necessary sizes in Windows are 16, **24**, 32, **48**, 64, 128, 256. Most scripts forgot those. I am unsure if 96 is really needed, but it doesn't hurt.
- You need to include 4-bit and 8-bit palette versions for the sizes 16, 24, 32 and 48 (apparently to support Remote Desktop applications in particular)

All in one bash script (starting from `logo.svg` and producing `logo.ico`):

```
#!/bin/bash

for size in 16 24 32 48 64 96 128 256; do
    inkscape --export-filename $size.png -w $size -h $size logo.svg >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
done

for size in 16 24 32 48; do

  convert -colors 256 +dither $size.png png8:$size-8.png
  convert -colors 16  +dither $size-8.png $size-4.png

done

convert 16.png 24.png 32.png 48.png 16-8.png 24-8.png 32-8.png 48-8.png 16-4.png 24-4.png 32-4.png 48-4.png 64.png 96.png 128.png 256.png logo.ico

rm 16.png 24.png 32.png 48.png 16-8.png 24-8.png 32-8.png 48-8.png 16-4.png 24-4.png 32-4.png 48-4.png 64.png 96.png 128.png 256.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Bash one-liner to convert `logo.svg` into `logo.ico`, using Inkscape to export the png images at various sizes:

```
eval convert \
  '<(inkscape -e /dev/stderr logo.svg -w '{16,24,32,48,64,128,256}' 2>&1 > /dev/null)' \
  logo.ico
```

Inspired by [Malcolm MacLeod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15099824/1366011), but avoiding the explicit loop and the temporary files.

The `stderr` and redirection is to avoid Inkscape's success message on `stdout` (“Bitmap saved as: /dev/stdout”) ending up in the image data.

Comment: A perfect solution is a little bit more complicated as 16,24,32,48 sizes need to be provided as 4-bit, 8-bit and 32-bit images.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying hnasarat's answer for windows users. The easiest way to is install InkScape and ImageMagick using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and then run the following in a batch file. (It is not as flexible as the other answers you just pass in one svg but it pumps out all the favicons recommended in [Favicon Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/audreyr/favicon-cheat-sheet).

```
@ECHO off

IF "%1"=="" (
    ECHO You must provide an svg file
    EXIT /b
) 

IF NOT EXIST favicons MD favicons

SET "sizes=16 24 32 48 57 64 72 96 120 128 144 152 195 228 256 512"

FOR %%s IN (%sizes%) DO (
    inkscape -z -e favicons/favicon-%%s.png -w %%s -h %%s %1
)

convert favicons/favicon-16.png favicons/favicon-24.png favicons/favicon-32.png favicons/favicon-48.png favicons/favicon-64.png favicons/favicon.ico
```

Comment: Hi, according to what I've read Imagick can't produce 512 icons, correct?

Answer (score 0):

To create an ICO file from a SVG while keeping aspect ratio:

1. look for SVG proportions (eg. 1920x1080)
2. for a max 256px wide icon, do the proportion: [1920:1080=256:x] -> x=(1080*256)/1920=144
3. finally, use ImageMagick `convert` command:

   convert -background none -resize 256x144 -gravity center -extent 256x144 image.svg image.ico