# Recipe to generate Windows ICO files with Graphicsmagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Based on this question for imagemagick, what is the equivalent for graphicsmagick? [Recipe for creating Windows ICO files with ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423711/recipe-for-creating-windows-ico-files-with-imagemagick)

Also I just want to generate a fully transparent ico file with multiple sizes. I found that there's an `xc:none` option that works for both, but is there one single command that generates ico files with multiple sizes that is transparent? Otherwise I would have to first create a transparent png file, then create ico files from the png file.

Comment: Are you stuck with using Windows to create this? Or can you use Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, **GraphicsMagick** doesn't support writing `ICO` format files - see [here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/formats.html).

Just in case anyone knows more about this mad Microsoft format and if it is maybe some sort of multi-page TIF or GIF in disguise that just needs to be renamed, the following would be one way of making a recipe in GraphicsMagick:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ echo convert image.png mpr:initial; 
  echo convert mpr:initial -resize 16x16 mpr:16;
  echo convert mpr:initial -resize 32x32 mpr:32;
  echo convert mpr:initial -resize 48x48 mpr:48;
  echo convert mpr:initial -resize 64x64 mpr:64;
  echo convert mpr:16 mpr:32 mpr:48 mpr:64 -colors 256 favicon.tif; } | gm batch -prompt off
```

For the moment, I have created a multi-page TIF as the output file and it contains the four sizes you need - but as I said, **GraphicsMagick** will not write a `ICO` file.

Comment: The format is described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format) .  You'd write the simple header and offset table, followed by a set of PNG datastreams.  GraphicsMagick doesn't support writing ICO files, but it probably wouldn't be difficult to implement.

Comment: wow, i thought ImageMagick and `gm` had feature parity... Guess I'll have to install IM, then!