# A very strange image/icon file (single file contains the same image with 3 different sizes)

Tags: html, css, image, favicon

I have this favicon file.

[Dowload favicon file](http://picturestack.com/969/551/HC2faviconFIv.ico)

I can not upload the image file since its does not have the proper format.

When you view this file in windows 7, you get the following.

[image: Page 1 of 3]

This single file contains the same image but at different sizes. The above shows page 1 of 3.

The following is page 2 of 3 which shows the same image but at a smaller size.

[image: page 2 of 3]

And than page 3 of 3 yet again at a more smaller size.

[image]

But it is one single file. My question is how is this possible and more importantly how can I make it such? A single file containing the same image with 3 diferrent sizes.

It shows 48px X 48px dimensions. And since favicon is used in web design/development, I have used the html & css tags.

Comment: There are many places where Windows will display icons of different sizes. Nice that icon file provides them - think 'small medium large' thumbnail choices in explorer

Comment: @n8wrl: No mate, maybe I could not explain better. It is a SINGLE file with the SAME image but at different SIZES. If you open the file in Adobe Photoshop or Adobe Illustrator, they will ask you which size image to import. The sizes are 16px X 16px, 32px X 32px and 48px X 48px.

Comment: Where are you trying to upload the file to and what does it consider the proper format? For non-IE browsers they can accept most types of graphic files so is it definitely not looking for a different file format entirely?

Comment: @Jawad: this is quite standard for icon files. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29 for details. The key thing is that they are designed to provide icons in multiple sizes so the software can decide what the most appropriate file is (eg icon on task bar is smaller than icon for shortcut on the desktop). The problem is more likely with where you are uploading the image since as far as I can tell from a quick browse of wikipedia there is no restrictions on how the ico files are structured.

Comment: @Chris: I meant I could not upload the file to stackoverflow since it allows png, jpeg file formats and hence the dowload link.

Comment: @Jawad: Ah, sorry. I misunderstood your question. I thought you were saying that the multiple images in a single file was causing you a problem for some reason. You're really just looking for a .ICO editor which I would imagine google could help with (though I would imagine all the big graphic editors could cope with them).

Comment: @Chris: Ah! Thanks mate. Just that I have seen such a thing for the first time. ONe never stops learning. Lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is just a feature of the `.ico` file format. Icons frequently need to be displayed at different resolutions, so the format allows different sizes to be packaged together in one file. Some Wikipedia pages on the subject:

[ICO (file format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29)

> The ICO file format is an image file format for computer icons in Microsoft Windows. ICO files contain one or more small images at multiple sizes and color depths, such that they may be scaled appropriately. In Windows, all executables that display an icon to the user, on the desktop, in the Start Menu, or in Windows Explorer, must carry the icon in ICO format.

[Favicon - HTML5 recommendation for icons in multiple sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#HTML5_recommendation_for_icons_in_multiple_sizes)

> The current HTML5 specification recommends specifying size icons in multiple sizes using the attributes `rel="icon" sizes="space-separated list of icon dimensions"` within a `<link>` tag.<sup>[35]</sup> Multiple icon formats, including container formats such as Microsoft `.ico` and Macintosh `.icns` files, as well as Scalable Vector Graphics may be provided by including the icon's content type in the form of `type="file content-type"` within the `<link>` tag.

To make such a file, you just need a program that is capable of editing `.ico` files and has access to that feature. The [How to make/get a multi size .ico file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354617/how-to-make-get-a-multi-size-ico-file) question goes into more detail on that.