# Visual C++ and exe icon size

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, win32gui

I have writed a small C++ program in Visual C++ 2012, I added a icon (contain multiple sizes and depths from 16x16 16bit to 256x256 32bit) but when compile, windows explorer doesn't show right icon size in other view modes (icon, detail, ...). How can i make my application icon change size in different explorer view mode or in different explorer zoom factor like notepad.exe (when you zoom the view, it get bigger or smaller)?

I have tried to build in VC++ 2010, VC++ 2008 but doesn't make better :-(

Comment: I expect it will show as same size in Notepad.exe icon (when zoom by CTRL + Scroll or change explorer view mode to Larger Icon) but i keep my app icon at 32x32 32bit :-(

Comment: Google "reset icon cache".

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks, but only my app keep icon size, others behavior is good, I think the problem in my app :-(

Comment: Have you actually tried reset the cache or are you just assuming that it doesn't apply?  It does.  You also *really* need to document the Windows version.

Comment: I have tried: http://www.winvistaclub.com/t71.html, but i think i meet issue in adding icon to GROUP_ICON in resource

Comment: You need a multilayer .ico file. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10819673/1545525