# How to get multiple icon file into Delphi resource file

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to generate a multi-size icon file to my Delphi app, so Windows will choose the best size to show in each situation.

Following the official support instructions at https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Creating_and_Deploying_App_Icons

> Storing Your Icon Files into an Icon Container
> Once you have your app
> icon in all the resolutions that a target platform requires, for
> desktop platforms you must then archive the different resolutions of
> your icon into a single file, an icon container, that you can deploy
> along with your application.
>
> For Windows, you must create an .ico icon container file. See How to
> make/get a multi size .ico file?."

It directs to this Stack Overflow question :

[How to make/get a multi size .ico file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354617/how-to-make-get-a-multi-size-ico-file)

I followed the instructions exactly as described and could get a multi-size icon file using ImageMagick.

Problem is , when i try to compile my resource file using BRCC32, i get this error :

[BRCC32 Error] icon.rc(2): Allocate failed

Here is the contents of my RC file :

```
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
MAINICON icon "myapp.ico"
```

If i go to Project > Application > Icons, i can load the myapp.ico without problems, but due to the nature of my project, i need to use a resource file instead.

Please help, i'm stuck on this issue for days.

Thanks

Comment: IIRC, the BRCC32 compiler doesn't support large icon files. Instead, you can use [RC](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/RC.EXE,_the_Microsoft_SDK_Resource_Compiler). From this page: "RC supports Unicode characters in resource files and file names, as well as new Vista resource types such as icons with alpha channel. "

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thanks but Delphi calls BRCC32 by itself everytime i compile... is there a way to change it to RC?

Comment: Doesn't the linked documentation page say how to change this?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Fount it. Thank you, please post as answer, this is valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on [resource compilers](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/RC.EXE,_the_Microsoft_SDK_Resource_Compiler):

> Both C++Builder and Delphi give you a choice of resource compilers. On the **Project > Options > Resource Compiler** dialog box, you can select either of the following:
>
> - BRCC32.exe, the C++Builder resource compiler
> - RC.exe, the Microsoft platform SDK Resource Compiler
>
> RC supports Unicode characters in resource files and file names, as well as new Vista resource types such as icons with alpha channel.

Hence, if you need Vista icons, you need to change to the RC compiler.