# In carrierwave, strip image but keep color profile OR convert color profile to sRGB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, minimagick

I'm having basically the same problem here:

[How to remove exif from a JPG without losing image quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646028/how-to-remove-exif-from-a-jpg-without-losing-image-quality/17516878#17516878)

But I'm using Rails and Carrierwave. I'm not sure how Robbert's solution converts to Ruby.

Any help would greatly be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [carrierwave docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Efficiently-converting-image-formats#full-example), you can add something like the following `mogrify` function to your uploader:

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process :mogrify

  # ...

  def mogrify
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.format('jpg') do |c|

        # other options you may want, eg:
        # c.auto_orient

        convert.profile.+('!icc,!xmp,*')
      end
      img
    end
  end
end
```

which will strip the EXIF data but preserve the ICC and XMP profiles in the JPG.

Comment: I noticed when updating my mini_magick gem to 4.2 (was 3.4) I had problems too. Try changing the two lines from my answer to this one line: `convert.profile.+('!icc,!xmp,*')`

Comment: Do XMP profiles exist in images?  I have only been able to find external xmp files that are stored alongside RAW files.

Comment: @fatfrog I don't have personal experience with embedding XMP metadata in images, but looking at the [XMP Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform#Embedding), it can be embedded in various image formats, including JPEGs. Hope that helps.