# Issue in removing Exif metadata from images without loss of quality or color

Tags: imagemagick, metadata

Referring to this link

[How to remove exif from a JPG without losing image quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646028/how-to-remove-exif-from-a-jpg-without-losing-image-quality/17516878#17516878)

I thought of doing

```
convert ~/Desktop/check.jpg profile.icm
convert ~/Desktop/check.jpg -strip -profile profile.icm output.jpg
```

When I did this, it is showing the error as

```
convert: UnableToTransformColorspace `/home/local/ZOHOCORP/valli-4204/Desktop/check.jpg' @ warning/profile.c/LCMSExceptionHandler/428.
convert: ColorspaceColorProfileMismatch `icc' @ error/profile.c/ProfileImage/831.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: In the referred link, it has been done successfully. Why cant i get that? Moreover I need to work with ImageMagick. using convert -strip I need solution

Comment: I know this is an old post but you need to get the ICC profile, strip the image and then add the ICC profile back in after

Answer (score 1):

Try `exiftool` as follows to remove all EXIF data without losing quality:

```
exiftool -all= image.jpg
```

You can achieve the same with `jhead` too:

```
jhead -purejpg image.jpg
```