# How to strip exif data from jpg image using Imagine/Imagick?

Tags: php, jpeg, imagick

I'd like to optimize **jpg** image size by deleting exif metadata from it. I use ***[Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)*** and ***[Imagine](https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)*** libraries to achieve this goal:

```
$image = $this->imagine->open($currentImagePath);

$iccProfile = $image->palette()->profile();

$image->strip();

$image->profile($iccProfile);

$image->save($optimizedImagePath);
```

But it doesn't work properly, it actually deletes all metadata from image including icc. Is there a way to delete just exif from jpg image using Imagine and Imagick?

Comment: You could write a simple program to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove exif from a JPG without losing image quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646028/how-to-remove-exif-from-a-jpg-without-losing-image-quality)