# Removing Apache2 Image Metadata Realtime

Tags: image, apache, security, exif, exiftool

I know there's many ways to remove image metadata on files.  Is there any Apache2 module or similar that can remove image metadata on the fly as it's streaming image data to the browser?  I'm wondering if there is any module that exists remove exif data inline.  Alternatively, a way to stream image data through ExifTool, remove metadata, then send to the browser.  The advantage of such a scheme is that original image files are unaltered yet metadata is cleaned for public consumption.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any Apache Modules to do that, and I believe this is not Apache's job.

If you are the only user for your website, you may run a shell script to remove exif meta data for all images.

Read more:
[Remove EXIF for multiple images with exiftool](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Blogs/Productivity-Sauce/Remove-EXIF-Metadata-from-Photos-with-exiftool)

If you are not the only user, it's better to implement this function in PHP (or others depends on which one you are running) and trigger the function when a new image has been uploaded.

Read more:

[How to remove exif from a JPG without losing image quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646028/how-to-remove-exif-from-a-jpg-without-losing-image-quality)

Comment: Understand.  I could not find any modules either.  Your solution is likely the best available and one I considered myself. I politely and respectfully disagree on what you consider is, "Apache's job".  Software developers should have a responsibility to keep those that use their software secure and safe.  Like a car has seat belts and airbags.  That said, I know the Apache HTTPD team is responsive to security concerns and addressing vulnerabilities.  The modules interface is probably the appropriate extent of their responsibility for exif filtering.