# File size went up instead of down when exif removed with PIL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, filesize

Not a huge deal, but for the sake of understanding what's going on to avoid future problems...

I'd like to know why the file size of a jpg is going up after the exif data is removed. I thought it was supposed to go down?

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open(fname)

name, ext = get_fname_ext(fname)

out_name = name + '_cleaned' + ext
out_abs = output_dir + "\\" + out_name

image.save(out_abs)
```

Filesize before: 192.65 KB

Filesize after:  202.46 KB

Difference: +9.82 KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that PIL recompresses the image (the source is a JPG, but it doesn't have to, so it's treated as image data). It would be safer/easier to rely on an external tool like [exiftool](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), imagemagick or [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/). The answers on [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654281/how-to-remove-exif-data-without-recompressing-the-jpeg) might be a good resource.

As an PIL-only alternative, you might try if the python snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786301/python-remove-exif-info-from-images) works for you:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('image_file.jpeg')

# next 3 lines strip exif
data = list(image.getdata())
image_without_exif = Image.new(image.mode, image.size)
image_without_exif.putdata(data)

image_without_exif.save('image_file_without_exif.jpeg')
```

Comment: The python snippet actually increased the size even more, so I'll use one of the other tools you've suggested.