# How to change resolution (DPI) of an image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, dpi

I have a JPEG picture with a DPI of 72. I want to change 72 dpi to 300 dpi.

How could I change resolution of JPEG pictures using C#?

Comment: DPI is relative -- it generally makes sense only in how it is rendered (e.g. to a printer or screen) or when it is read in (e.g. from a scanner). Saving the DPI in these cases allows for an exact-size reproduction, for instance. The [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data that can be stored inside JPEG (but not 2k) images is where the DPI information is kept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030706.asp) talks about modifying the [EXIF data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) without the re-saving/re-compressing (and thus loss of information -- it actually uses a "trick"; there may be more direct libraries) required by the `SetResolution` approach. This was found on a quick google search, but I wanted to point out that all you *need* to do is modify the stored EXIF data.

[Also: .NET lib for EXIF modification](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=C%23+modify+exif) and another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038206/net-c-library-for-lossless-exif-rewriting). Google owns when you know good search terms.

Comment: Lossless being a key information, but the edit queue is full.

Answer (score 75):

You have to copy the bits over a new image with the target resolution, like this:

```
    using (Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("file.jpg"))
    {
        using (Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap))
        {
            newBitmap.SetResolution(300, 300);
            newBitmap.Save("file300.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should also mention that in case of JPEG, the saving to a new file will cause additional compression losses

Comment: Absolutely, we can observe that the file gets smaller and smaller each time

Comment: Is there a reason you have to *copy* the bitmap rather than just call `SetResolution` on the original?

Comment: If I try to draw a lower resolution bitmap in another higher resolution bitmap, the image will be "cut off". your solution works for me. I just need to match the two bitmap's resolution

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that this does not work in .NET 5.0 on Linux/Docker.

Comment: In python, it is possible to modify the exif without modifying the image https://stackoverflow.com/a/53554491/4575793
I'm convinced that this is possible in C# too.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply a matter of scaling the image width and height up by the correct ratio.  Not all images formats support a DPI metatag, and when they do, all they're telling your graphics software to do is divide the image by the ratio supplied.

For example, if you export a 300dpi image from Photoshop to a JPEG, the image will appear to be very large when viewed in your picture viewing software.  This is because the DPI information isn't supported in JPEG and is discarded when saved.  This means your picture viewer doesn't know what ratio to divide the image by and instead displays the image at at 1:1 ratio.

To get the ratio you need to scale the image by, see the code below.  Just remember, this *will* stretch the image, just like it would in Photoshop. You're essentially quadrupling the size of the image so it's going to stretch and may produce artifacts.

**Pseudo code**

```
ratio = 300.0 / 72.0   // 4.167
image.width * ratio
image.height * ratio
```

Answer (score -1):

This code using merge and convert 200 dbi

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        { Path string Outputpath = @"C:\Users\MDASARATHAN\Desktop\TX_HARDIN_10-01-2016_K";

            string[] TotalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Outputpath, "*.tif", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string filename in TotalFiles)
            {

                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filename);

                string ExportFilename = string.Empty;
                int Pagecount = 0;
                bool bFirstImage = true;
                bitmap.SetResolution(200, 200);

                ExportFilename = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename) + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(filename)+"f";
                MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
                Pagecount = bitmap.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);

                if (bFirstImage)
                {
                    bitmap.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                    bFirstImage = false;
                } Image tiff = Image.FromStream(byteStream);
                ImageCodecInfo encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(i => i.MimeType == "image/tiff");
                EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(2);
                EncoderParameter parameter = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
                encoderParams.Param[0] = parameter;
                parameter = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
                encoderParams.Param[1] = parameter;
              //  bitmap.Dispose();
                try
                {

                    tiff.Save(ExportFilename, encoderInfo, encoderParams);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                EncoderParameters EncoderParams = new EncoderParameters(2);
                EncoderParameter SaveEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                EncoderParameter CompressionEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Compression, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionCCITT4);
                EncoderParams.Param[0] = CompressionEncodeParam;
                EncoderParams.Param[1] = SaveEncodeParam;
                if (bFirstImage == false)
                {

                    for (int i = 1; i < Pagecount; i++)
                    {

                            //bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(filenames);
                            byteStream = new MemoryStream();
                            bitmap.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, i);
                            bitmap.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                            bitmap.SetResolution(200, 200);
                            tiff.SaveAdd(bitmap, EncoderParams);

                    }

                } SaveEncodeParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.SaveFlag, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                EncoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
                EncoderParams.Param[0] = SaveEncodeParam;
                tiff.SaveAdd(EncoderParams);
                tiff.Dispose();
                bitmap.Dispose();
                File.Delete(filename);

            }


        }
```

Comment: can you pls explain how this would resolve the issue?

Comment: This code explains how to merge a bunch of single-page TIFF images into a multi-page TIFF; it doesn't appear related to the question at all.

Answer (score -2):

DPI should not be stored in an bitmap image file, as most sources of data for bitmaps render it meaningless.

A bitmap image is stored as pixels.  Pixels have no inherent size in any respect.  It's only at render time - be it monitor, printer, or automated crossstitching machine - that DPI matters.

A 800x1000 pixel bitmap image, printed at 100 dpi, turns into a nice 8x10" photo.  Printed at 200 dpi, the *EXACT SAME* bitmap image turns into a 4x5" photo.

Capture an image with a digital camera, and what does DPI mean?  It's certainly not the size of the area focused onto the CCD imager - that depends on the distance, and with NASA returning images of galaxies that are 100,000 light years across, and 2 million light years apart, in the same field of view, what kind of DPI do you get from *THAT* information?

Don't fall victim to the idea of the DPI of a bitmap image - it's a mistake.  A bitmap image  has no physical dimensions (save for a few micrometers of storage space in RAM or hard drive).  It's only a displayed image, or a printed image, that has a physical size in inches, or millimeters, or furlongs.

Comment: DPI is used to interpret the physical meaning of the pixels. So your info is right and your conclusion is wrong. DPI is useful and often necessary for working with bitmap files.