# Webmatrix image uploader (change quality to 72dpi)

Tags: image, image-processing, webmatrix, webmatrix-2

I am currently building a new website in WebMatrix, and have successfully added functionality to upload and resize images using the image helper. My question is, does this tool have the functionality to change resolution too? i'm concerned that people will upload pics taken with high resolution cameras, and even though i resize the images, they are still large in file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebImage helper (if that's what you are using) doesn't incorporate advanced image manipulation features. You can write your own code to change an image's resolution once the image has been saved - or borrow some that someone else has already written, such as the highest voted answer to [this SO question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427059/how-to-change-resolution-dpi-of-an-image).