# When does Bitmap '.resx' file compile?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, embedded-resource, dpi

I have strange observation on resource file  '**Images.resx**' contains all images as'.PNG' designed at 96 dpi.

Build action: Embedded Resource

**While Debugging at 120 DPI(125 %)**

```
Bitmap myIcon=Images.Icon;
```

> ***myIcon*** Horizontal and vertical resolution as 95.9866

```
Bitmap myIcon = new Bitmap(Images.Icon);
```

> **myIcon** Horizontal and vertical resolution as 120

Requirement is to merge Images. Based on whether Image is re-initialized  or not Image Scales improperly (on dpi >96).
How to fix this behavior ?

**System:**
VisualStudio 2017,
Winform

Comment: Can't you specify the dpi of the bitmap when you create it?

Comment: with visual studio No i guess

Comment: This is by design.  Any *new* Bitmap you create records the resolution of the video adapter.  Assigning its Horizontal/VerticalResolution properties is the workaround.

Comment: exactly. because *actual* resolution is a property of a rendering device, not of the picture (that does not mean that the resolution property on the bitmap is useless: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13995552/1132334)