# "parameter is not valid" while converting bytes to image using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays, image, byte

I saved my image to MySql Database using wamp server localhost but when i am trying to retrieve image from MySql and convert the image from bytes to image it gives the error parameter is not valid, i used many techniques and many solution but in vain, i user image converter and memory stream but didn't wok for me i am pasting my code please help me its very important.

```
byte[] img;

MySqlCommand cmd_image = new MySqlCommand("Select image from logindetails where Username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'", con);
MySqlDataReader Image_Reader = cmd_image.ExecuteReader();
            while (Image_Reader.Read())
            {
                img = (byte[])Image_Reader["Image"];
            }

            System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
            Image image = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(img);
            pictureBox1.Image = image;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byte Array to Image Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173904/byte-array-to-image-conversion)

Comment: This is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: The only thing that really matters to answer this question is, In what format is the image _saved_ in the database?

Answer (score 0):

`ImageConverter` is used to convert images, not create them. Use the code below:

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(img))
    {
        using (Image imageFromStream = Image.FromStream(memoryStream))
        {
            bitmap = new Bitmap(imageFromStream);
        }
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

Note that if your byte array does not hold an image you will still get the same error.

Comment: i tried to your code but it is giving the same error

Comment: and array img has 13 bytes

Comment: @UsmanLiaqat What is the data type of the column image in the table logindetails?

Comment: [Don't create an image from a memory stream you dispose. It's against specifications.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48579791/395685) There are workarounds for this.

Comment: 13 bytes seems rather little to create an image from. Are you sure that's actual image data? It barely seems enough to be a path to a file, or even just a filename...

Comment: @UsmanLiaqat 13 bytes is indeed unbelievably small. A small logo is easily 2000 bytes. This could be wrong data which is why you are still receiving the same error.

Comment: @Nyerguds You are correct, I just tested it. I thought it was only for storing images to files. But indeed after the stream is disposed the image can no longer be viewed. I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: You should also dispose the image you made from the stream, though.